# Class File Editor, Source not found for any of my files

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been coding in Java Eclipse and haven't had a problem until now. My problem is that all of my files have stopped being accessible by Eclipse. I can open any project and got to any file but Eclipse just says Class File Editor Source not found There is no source file attached to the class file Anyclass.class I have gone over videos and other guides on how to fix this problem, but those only address what to do when one file is missing. I open any file from any project and it gives me this error. Any class I try to open gives me the same Class File Editor Source not found error. I have spent the better part of four hours attempting to fix this problem, and nothing has worked. All of my files are on the computer and in proper places, but Eclipse can't find them. What do I do in order to get my files back so I can continue working on code?

Comment: Could you please show a screenshot of your issue?